# Is superuser.com or another StackExchange site an appropriate way to ask information about websites?

Tags: discussion, websites

I was going to post to superuser.com a question of "I had a rough encounter with X; people should really be warned. Where besides Yelp should I post?" However, I'm not sure that questions about websites are appropriate in superuser.com.

Is superuser.com an appropriate place to ask about websites, and if it isn't, is there another appropriate place to post it, or is this presently not covered by the StackExchange mantle?

Thanks,

Comment: what is "X" in this context?

Comment: Regarding your question about "what is 'X'", a university that in my opinion not only incompetent in grading, but incompetent enough to put me as a student in danger of losing my life. Details at http://JonathansCorner.com/dell-hell-education

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like that wouldn't be a proper question for Super User.

In fact, a question like that is probably not a good fit for any other site on the network, because it is a type of question that would cause users to post a random recommendation for a given site.

These types of answers often lose value over time, because websites die or are no longer relevant for other reasons.

So it sounds like it would best be discussed on chat. You should join us in [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118/root-access) and see if someone has some nice advice for you.